# dplyr/sparklyr "OR" Join

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I know it is possible to join on two columns using `sparklyr` like so:

```
final <- tbl1 %>% left_join(tbl2, by = c("x1" = "x2", "y1" = "y2"))
```

But is there a way to join two columns like below in my `impala` sql query:

```
select 
 a.col1
,b.col2
from tbl1 a


left join
(select * from tbl1 )b
on a.id = b.id 
and(                           a.date1  = b.date1 
                                     or 
                          a.date2 = b.date2               )
```

I would imagine it would be something like:

```
final <-  tbl1 %>% left_join(tbl2, by = c("x1" = "x2",c("y1" = "y2" or "y3" = "y4")))
```

Comment: No, not with `dplyr` (to my knowledge). But you could use `sqldf` package to run it in SQL. Or you could hack it in pieces, do two separate joins and then union and de-duplicate the results.

Comment: Merge then filter, something like: `left_join(tbl1, tbl2, by = c("x1" = "x2")) %>% filter(y1 == y2 | y3 == y4)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use SQL:

```
df1 %>% sdf_register("tbl1")
df2 %>% sdf_register("tbl2")

query <- "select ..."

result <- sc %>% spark_session() %>% invoke("sql", query) %>% sdf_register()
```

Note that you might have to alias columns to avoid duplicate names in the output.